# react-native existing app crash on Android 4.1

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I try to run my existing React-Native app on Android 4.1.x version. My app work for Android 5 and more, but crash on 4.1.x.

After installing apk (in dev mode, not release), i've simply an error `app has stopped`.

I don't know how i can debug this ... i don't have any error message for try to fix the problem.

Anyone have already this usecase ? My test are with [this open source project](https://github.com/stephane-r/HoloPlay)

Thank you !

EDIT : i've found error on Android Studio :

```
D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
I/ActivityThread: Pub com.holoplay.lifecycle-process: androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9e6c7228)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4548)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could you post your error message [logcat] ?

Comment: I've edit my first post :) `Permission denied` and `AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`. I don't really understand why ^^

Comment: You can try to rebuild the app in and install it again. let me know if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you added necessary implementations in gradle file. If yes, then it might be cache issue.

Comment: Build -> Clean Project and File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...try this

Comment: Same result. But i've this "warning" (not error) on run device : `Unable to strip library '/home/stephane/Project/HoloPlay/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/home/stephane/Project/HoloPlay/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.`

Comment: you can use with administration permission